# Sitecore Analytics Error - Item buckets

Tags: sitecore, analytics

We are seeing an issue in the Sitecore log files, the message says - "Cannot use Analytics with a database that has no definition items". We have not enabled Analytics in our Sitecore environment. Is anyone aware of this error ?

Here is the stack trace that I found from Sitecore log file

```html
2764 2015:02:24 14:11:17 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Cannot use Analytics with a database that has no definition items
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ResultNotNull[T](T result, String message)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Commons.LazyReference`1.GetValue(Object mutex, Func`1 initializer)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.AnalyticsItems.<get_Profiles>b__7()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Commons.LazyReference`1.GetValue(Object mutex, Func`1 initializer)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.NormalizeProfiles(AnalyticsItems analytics)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.TrackingField.InitializeProfiles()
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.UI.DynamicFields.EngagementValue.IsLockedCheck(DynamicFieldsArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.UI.DynamicFields.EngagementValue.Process(DynamicFieldsArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.UI.DynamicFields.DynamicFieldsPipeline.Run(DynamicFieldsArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.UI.FillItem.SetItemProperties.GetValue(Item innerItem, SitecoreUISearchResultItem sitecoreItem)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.UI.FillItem.SetItemProperties.GetQuickActions(FillItemArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.UI.FillItem.FillItemPipeline.Run(FillItemArgs args)
   at ItemBuckets.Services.Search.<ProcessRequestAsync>d__d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.TaskAsyncHelper.EndTask(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Let me know if additional information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace shows the following method is being called:
`Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.UI.DynamicFields.EngagementValue.IsLockedCheck`

In that method, a `TrackingField` object is instantiated which in turn calls it's own method `InitializeProfiles` (This also appears in the stack trace).

The thing is, that `TrackingField` object is only created if the value of the static `Settings.Analytics.Enabled` property is true, and there are 2 elements required for this:

- The `Analytics.Enabled`setting in the `Sitecore.Analytics.config` file must be set to true.
- The Sitecore licence must include DMS.

Are you sure you don't have analytics enabled, because it seems Sitecore thinks you do.

Comment: We don't have the Sitecore.Analytics.Config file added in our CMS environment.Our license file includes DMS, but the analytics isn't enabled though.

Comment: Please can you run `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` and search the page for "analytics.enabled"

Comment: I had checked the showconfig.aspx page already, and there is no sign of "analytics.enabled" term. I guess this is because we don't have the Sitecore.Analytcis.config file in the App_Config/Include folder (Analytics not being enabled).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help then. This all rests on the `Settings.Analytics.Enabled` property returning true instead of the default false. I recommend raising a bug with Sitecore, or simply removing the `DynamicFields.EngagementValue` processor from the pipeline. It's only used for analytics related stuff anyway.